# What does multi area OSPF mean?

Tags: ospf

Does this mean that all the routers in a given topology should have different values of area or just one i.e. area 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `OSPF` use a single area but when you have a large network and you want some network segmentation, you can use a multi area network. In General multi area is not used in small environments.

When you have a large environment, a multi area network reduces processing overhead. It requires a hierarchical design, and has a main area called **backbone**  area which must be `area 0`. Additionally all other area needs to be connected to the backbone area.

[More Details](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/open-shortest-path-first-ospf/118879-configure-ospf-00.html)

Comment: So basically  I am asked to draw a topology in which 5 routers are interlinked and configured on multi area OSPF. Will I do it like this that I will keep one router at the center and place all 4 routers around it. I'll give the center one area 0 and the rest 1,2,3?

Comment: It does not mean, one should be in center. But Your area '0' should be able to talk to all areas directly. Other hand your all areas should be connected to area '0'  Please refer link

https://www.google.com/search?q=multi+area+ospf&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJku3Io6LiAhXMMY8KHY2GBg8Q_AUIDigB&biw=1366&bih=604#imgrc=_8q_dtWp5fpx7M:

Comment: but these pictures don't show that how will I connect one router to other 4?

Comment: There may be more than one possible ways, what we need to do is, area '0' directly contact other areas. Please refer link which is posted in answer. it has separate topology and you can any number of areas by extending that topology